# What do we know about (trouble with) the writing process for Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Beginning in Season 5 (if not earlier) I've been noticing what I consider to be increasingly serious and extensive failures in the writing for GoT.

- Some of it was not technically weak on the face of it, but plot-wise seemed to make no sense. 
  Examples: [LittleFinger's Shennanings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90112/whats-the-use-of-littlefingers-latest-shenanigans-season-5-episodes-67) which  I asked about last year -

  > Marrying Sansa off to Ramsey Bolton with no apparent benefit. Even now, near the end of Season 6, it is still unlikely it would be justified in retrospect.
- Some of it is a whole branch of the plot going awry, namely Dorne:

  > Doran essentially does nothing. Areo Hotah - essentially does nothing. There being no noble houses in Dorne to speak of, no politics, no nothing. The Mircella kiss-of-death scene which was incredibly obvious. The magic teleportation of two of the Sand Snakes from Dorne to King's Landing and their no less magical boarding of Tristane's ship. etc.

  and this gets a "gruesome fix" in the form of

  > just suddenly killing everyone off in Season 6 Episode 1. I'm surprised they didn't all commit suicide afterwards to lay that story to rest for good.
- And now in Season 6 we see ever more examples of central protagonists acting prima facie unreasonably:

  > Faceless men draw attention to themselves by causing commotions in the middle of busy streets. Arya Stark, knowing she's likely to be chased by a face-changing assassin, not taking the least bit of precaution either in walking around, nor standing in conspicuous spots for a long time, nor suspecting strangers who approach her. Jaime Lannister, the Lord Commander of King's Guard, not bothering to have a clue where his king is at. The Lannisters and the Tyrels waiting for the High Septon's moment of choice rather than just subtly storming the place earlier (something they had already done on some occasion in previous seasions). Davos Seaworth somehow forgetting all about his life with Stannis and Shireen Barratheon and becoming a devotee of Jon Snow and buddies with Melisandre. Night's king not bothering to send a few of his million zombies around the Three-Eyed Crow's cave. Nobody caring about the Lord Commander of the Night's Watch abandoning his post and taking up his old house's politics.
- And an increase in the prominence of Deus Ex-Machina scenes

  > Like Brienne finding Sansa just in the nick of time. And Benjen saving Bran and Meera. Maybe Theon Grayjoy's magic jet-pack ride to Pyke also counts, and probably also the magical funhouse of the Dosh Khaleen which could really not have killed any of the Khals.

Now, this is not a rant, it's a question (I just had to give some basis for my factual claim):

- Isn't there some kind of review process for the script writers? You would think dozens of people would look at script drafts before they're finalized, more than enough to mend larger holes and gloss over the smaller points.
- What's GRRM's involvement in this? Obviously the show and the books have diverged a whole lot by now, but still, he *is* associated with the show.
- Has there been some internal politics in play with the show's management which might account for some of this? Sometimes TV shows have a writing quality drop between seasons for these kinds of reasons.
- Or maybe it's just me being to finicky about things? I don't know, it doesn't seem that incredibly hard to maintain better consistency.

I'm truly puzzled and dismayed.

Comment: I think this question risks being too broad **and** primarily opinion-based **and** too many questions, all at once. :-) Maybe it should be edited to focus on one of the more answerable part (GRRM's involvement, for example).

Comment: Honestly even though you claim this isn't a rant, it sounds like one. I do agree with the frustration, just not sure if this is a good question for this site.

Comment: @ifurini: But if I remove the rant'y part I will not have provided a proper basis for my claim about the deterioration in the writing...

Comment: There are too many questions and far too much rant for this to be effectively answered. Maybe just don't watch the show if you don't like it?

Comment: I agree with you 100%, however this isn't the place for us to vent or rant about these things. You're welcome to discuss these points in the [GoT Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39179/game-of-thrones-spoiler-chat)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is a "I'm thinking this, what do you think?" type question and is off-topic: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @Mooz: But that's not what I asked. And you'll notice there's a _very_ interesting answer (albeit not completely satisfactory IMO).

Comment: You might like this: https://np.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/4mqmd3/spoilers_extended_reactions_game_of_thrones/d3xr8ym

Comment: @BCdotWEB: I wish the question had not been put on hold, because differences among indiividual writers might account for a lot of the issues I mentioned. Thanks and consider voting for a re-open so I can properly up-vote that...

Comment: Sorry, this does read like a rant. It reads like "there is this bunch of things I don't like about the show, please tell me about problems with the writing".

Comment: @BCdotWEB That rant is silly. Sure, some things didn't make sense -- they often don't in TV shows -- but I loved Ian McShane's character, he didn't "ham it up", and it was a great episode for The Hound. I *really* thought this re-introduction of The Hound was very well done.

Comment: @AndresF.: 1. Even if you find the rant silly, the questions are valid - as you can tell by the answer and the discussion BCdotWEB linked to. 2. Having enjoyable parts of the writing does not mean it has no failings w.r.t. consistency.

Comment: @einpoklum This is subjective, but while of course all questions are "valid", I found them silly, and the ensuing discussion uninteresting. Ian McShane's (brief) participation was interesting, it gave us a glimpse of a possible different lifestyle for The Hound, and the overall consensus on the web is that it was a good episode. Complaints of rabid fans nonwithstanding :)

Answer (score 10):

If you look at your examples for when the show has 'deteriorated', there is a common denominator.

**The show is not able to(or chooses not to) use the book source material and the author of the source material is less involved..**

George RR Martin does still have a role in determining the direction of the show, but it is smaller since the show passed the books.

While GRRM is contractually a part of GoT and will not criticize it openly, it can be inferred that he is not necessarily happy with all of the changes by looking at the timing of his preview chapter releases.

- Sansa chapter in the Vale released right after Sansa was married to Ramsey.
- Arianne Martell chapter released right after the Dorne murders described in the question.
- Aeron Damphair chapter read right after the Ironborn Kings Moot. (Thanks @Mooz for reminding me of this one.)

With these chapters, he seems to be saying, "Look, *I* didn't screw up these storylines".
[Here's a quote discussing the timing of the Dorne chapter release:](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2016/05/game-of-thrones-george-rr-martin-chapter-winds-of-winter-dorne)

> The timing of this chapter release is even more suspicious given that it isn’t technically new. Martin has been reading “Arianne II” aloud to fans at conventions since 2011. .... it also contains lines like, “Prince Trystane had remained safely back at Sunspear, after a tearful parting from Princess Myrcella.” Quite the contrast, no?

In addition to that, [GRRM has backed away from the show](http://www.vulture.com/2014/07/george-rr-martin-winds-of-winter-over-show.html) as he commits more time to writing the next book.

> (Interviewer) Which shooting location are you going to choose to visit this season? ....
>
> (GRRM) I don’t know. I might make it over there early next year, but I’ve got to finish the book The Winds of Winter....  So I don’t think I’m going to do a set visit this year, sadly.
>
> (Interviewer) You still going to write an episode?
>
> (GRRM) Not this year, no — once again because I have this book to finish.

This interview was before Season Five, however it does apply to Season Six as well.

Comment: While this correlation probably has a lot to do with it, not having book material to go by should not result in the kind of major failings I describe. I mean, sure, they could have plots that meander, or developments which are less inspiring, but even with no GRRM to hold the writers' hands, they should still not be getting it _that_ bad. But - the chapter release timings may be telling like you suggest

Comment: @einpoklum I'll probably do some more looking into it tonight, see if there's any more info.  At the very least, the GRRM chapters seem to suggest that there's trouble in paradise.

Comment: Also the Aeron chapter straight after the silly Kingsmoot.

Comment: @Mooz oohh.  Forgot about that one.  If you don't mind, I'll add that to the list.

Comment: @kuhl Go for it mate. Just FYI for future: my comments are "fair game".

Comment: I *seriously* doubt GRRM released the preview chapters "in time" to contradict alleged plot-holes in the TV show. By the way, it's not as if the books themselves aren't full of plot-holes, dead-ends and characters doing nonsensical things. This often happens in fiction. It's not serious. I doubt GRRM is miffed about a show which managed to improve some of his meandering plot lines, like the infamous "Meereenese Knot".

Comment: @AndresF.: 1. Examples please re the books. 2. You "seriously doubt" - ok, but that's purely subjective; what is the factual basis for your doubt?

Comment: @AndresF. The chapter release thing is speculation, but there are lots of people who believe this. I've added a quote and a link to an article talking about this issue in more detail. And just think, if you have people complaining about your life's work, because a TV show that is making you rich changed up a storyline, what are you going to do? You can't really speak out against the show, like I said it's in your best interests for the show to be profitable. What you can do, is put out chapters that more subtly remind people that in your universe, these scenes aren't possible and don't happen.

Comment: @einpoklum 1. Too many to list. Daenerys in Meereen, GRRM himself admitted it didn't work and he didn't know how to solve it (google it). Arya in Braavos seems like a dead-end at this point, though with enjoyable parts. Lady Stoneheart is mostly a dead-end character as well. *A Feast for Crows* is a filler book with (mostly) uninteresting characters. And many more flaws... which in my opinion don't detract from the story, because all fiction has flaws. 2. You have the onus of the proof backwards. I don't have to prove my doubts; you have to prove the allegation is sensible :)

Comment: @AndresF. For point number 2, see my above comment and the link/quote I've added to the answer.

Comment: @AndresF.: These are all examples of narrative dead-ends, not of characters acting non-sensically/inconsistently. They might be poor choices of where to lead the plot, but you don't get the sense of "Come on, character X would _not_ do that!" - and with the show, you do.

Comment: @einpoklum This is very subjective territory :) In my opinion, the books have moments with characters doing nonsensical stuff, and plot-holes. No, I can't give you a list, it's been a while since I read them. The TV show is fresh in my mind, however, and while it obviously has plot-holes, none are too egregious that I feel the need to post a rant online :) In contrast, the TV show has -- successfully, in my opinion -- trimmed down almost all of the fat in GRRM's writing, making the right compromises along the way. Where it has flaws, they were also in the original (like Dorne leading nowhere)

Comment: @AndresF.: You'll eventually come round to accept the [Dornish Master Plan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TBfdd_xNVo&index=1&list=PLCsx_OFEYH6uvfZSfec35DXBEpvA9fpm0)...